# Is it possible to use a vim color theme with eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, vim, plugins

I really love the [Molokai](http://winterdom.com/2008/08/molokaiforvim) plugin in my gvim, and I would like to use it with Eclipse. Is it possible to do this somehow?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: In the worst case, I am ready to configure the Eclipse colors manually, but I want to be able to use the [font](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/05/26/envy-code-r-preview-7-coding-font-released) that Molokai uses. How can I get this font to work with Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your EDIT, in Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Basic you can double-click on "Text Font" and set it to whatever font you have installed on your system.

I use the zenburn theme, provided by the plugin linked by Grammin and Inconsolata 14.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/ its the best one out there and works pretty well.